# forEach not returning a value to outer function like for loop does

Tags: javascript

I was trying to put a return in my `foreach`, but it returns `undefined`. But when I put the same `if` statement in a `for loop`, it returns the correct value. Why is this happening?

```
this.SpriteAndHull.forEach(element => {
      if (element.name == name) {
        return element;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `.forEach()` Your `return` statement returns from the function being passed into the forEach callback, not the outer function.

*Edit: It should be noted that returning from the `.forEach()` function does nothing, as `.forEach()` (by design) does not support a return value and will always return `undefined`*

One thing you can do is to set the element and then return it, or simply use a different iterator function, like so:

```
function getElementByName(elems, name) {
  let elem;

  elems.forEach(element => {
    if (element.name === name) {
      elem = element;
    }
  });

  return elem;
}
```

or:

```
function getElementByName(elems, name) {
  return elems.find(element => element.name === name);
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would I get the return value from the callback?

Comment: @MikeOttink with `.forEach()` you don't. There is no return value from that particular iterator - it's always `undefined`. But you could use something like `.filter()` or `.find()` to get a return value.

Answer (score 3):

Because `forEach` always returns `undefined` (in effect), and it completely ignores the return value of the callback, if any. Your `return element` is in the callback, so it's ignored.

You probably want a `for-of` loop instead:

```
for (const element of this.SpriteAndHull) {
    if (element.name == name) {
        return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for...of` is a great alternative to a functional approach, and will yield better performance. +1'd

Comment: .forEach isn't really functional, it's just method chaining. Map/filter/reduce are functional because they emphasize immutability.

Comment: @BadHeuristics True, I should have clarified, I meant functional as "using a function to iterate" rather than functional as a programming paradigm

Comment: @mhodges - Thanks. :-) The real performance benefit (not that it likely matters) over `forEach` is stopping early when found. Your `find` solution has that same benefit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed - short circuiting can be a good performance gain, but another source of big gains comes from not introducing a function on the call stack - this becomes especially important with recursive functions. In 99.9% of cases, it won't make any difference, though. Just thought it was worth mentioning for future readers if they're trying to understand the difference between the posted solutions.

Comment: @mhodges - Yes indeed. Of course, *theoretically*, iteration like `for-of` involves function calls. But unless you've mucked with `Array.prototype`, we can be fairly sure the JavaScript engine will optimize most of that away in hot code... :-)

Answer (score -2):

What you want is `find`

```
// element will either ben the element that matches the name, or it will be undefined if nothing is found
const element = this.SpriteAndHull.find(el => el.name === name);
```